# Devise Async, throws error after rails upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

After upgrading to Rails 3.1.10, with Device version 2.2.3, Device Async throws the following error,

```
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-async-0.6.0/lib/devise/async.rb:42:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `add_module' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-async-0.6.0/lib/devise-async.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
from /devel/off/ruby/rails/aodb/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `require'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any idea what to be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Moving "gem devise-async" below "gem devise" solves this issue.

Comment: Does anyone has an answer for why this needs to be done?